# Is it possible to simultaneously infer possible keys and enforce object values interface?

Tags: typescript, object, generics, properties, type-inference

I have an config object in which every object value should be typed according to specified interface, but I also want to infer possible keys from that same object without defining them dynamically as strings.

I have interface for each object value:

```js
interface PageConfig {
    url: string;
    title: string;
    allow?: string;
    path?: string;
    icon?: SpriteSymbol | string;
    component?: () => any;
}
```

So basically what I'm trying to do (obviously this won't work cause of recursive reference):

```js
type PagesConfig {
    [key in keyof PagesConfig]: PageConfig
}

const pages: PagesConfig = {
    home: {
        url: '/',
        title: 'home',
        component: () => import('Home'),
    },
    rules: {
        url: '/static/rules',
        title: 'rules',
        component: () => import('Rules'),
    },
    about: {
        url: '/static/about',
        title: 'about',
        component: () => import('About'),
    },
};
```

I've came up with two solutions that actually work as intended but are a bit ugly.

1. Use function to create config

```js
function createPages<Pages extends { [key: string]: PagesConfig }>(pages: Pages): { [key in keyof Pages]: PageConfig } {
    return pages;
}
```

2. Use helper variable to obtain keys

```js
const proto = {
    home: {
        url: '/',
        title: 'home',
        component: () => import('Home'),
    },
    rules: {
        url: '/static/rules',
        title: 'rules',
        component: () => import('Rules'),
    },
    about: {
        url: '/static/about',
        title: 'about',
        component: () => import('About'),
    },
};

const pages: {
    [key in keyof typeof proto]: PageConfig
} = proto;
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that my goal is to ensure that simultaneously every value (page object) in `pages` config follow structure specified by `PageConfig` interface (otherwise developer should see typescript error indicating that it doesn't) and also benefit from autocomplete when using `pages` config in other files - so any developer will know that for example `rules` page has `component` property when using `pages.rules.component` but see error when trying to access property that isn't there like `pages.rules.icon`.

So basically I need to make sure that pages config is built properly and also know it's structure when importing it elsewhere.

Comment: A function is the usual way I recommend doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```js
const pages = {
    home: {
        url: '/',
        title: 'home',
        component: () => null,
    } as PageConfig,
    rules: {
        url: '/static/rules',
        title: 'rules',
        component: () => null,
    } as PageConfig,
    about: {
        url: '/static/about',
        title: 'about',
        component: () => null,
    } as PageConfig,
} as const;
```

Note the **`as const`** at the bottom.

And then you can define your `PagesConfig` like this:

```js
types PagesConfig = typeof pages;
```

This requires using the `as PageConfig` in the creation of your pages object... you can remove this by using a more complicated type setup using mapped types:

```js
const pages = {
    home: {
        url: '/',
        title: 'home',
        component: () => null,
    },
    rules: {
        url: '/static/rules',
        title: 'rules',
        component: () => null,
    },
    about: {
        url: '/static/about',
        title: 'about',
        component: () => null,
    },
} as const;

// this is now very specific and does not contain references to `PageConfig`
type _SpecificPagesConfig = typeof pages;

// used to convert specific pages to the general `PageConfig` type
type _AsPages<T> = {
    [I in keyof T]: PageConfig;
}

// finally you have the 'correct' type
// { home: PageConfig; rules: PageConfig; about: PageConfig; }
type PagesConfig = _AsPages<_SpecificPagesConfig>;
```

(Or in the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgcwgYQPYDsBmBLBUC8U6ArgLYBGEATgNwBQdAxhgM7BRiIQsFQDedKEKgALVKQgAufoOFziVADbSA5AHoVAGllyhwbMEVSoKsRK07dzUmAwR0waQAoAlAQB8RYosXa5AXz9hKm9uaQFdYQVlEzU2OH1GNRCjFgtIvQMjVRTudIzrW3R7RyhXDy8fIKFAyzhyVGJSiIzo1TjgBOwk+sbgfMj9Q2MVXqaBq3Eikuc3fE8SKsta-yg4HmZ0Nno6UEgoAH0AZUhGbBxGeCQWNCxcXj2IVEwOLhYdx8OAQRYr7gAeAAqnkILSEAG0AJJQbDoKAAawgIGeUEBAF1pH9bjgEPR-AxPn8bhgcbwDj8if9jqdzt0idjcO4aEA))

Now this has the problem, that `pages` itself is not properly typed check. We can statically assert, that `pages` conforms by altering the types a bit:

```js
type _AsPages<T> = {
    [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends PageConfig ? PageConfig : 'error';
}

// to assert, that PagesConfig is valid
type __CheckOnlyPageConfigs<T extends { [k: string]: PageConfig }> = { }
type __check = __CheckOnlyPageConfigs<PagesConfig>
```

Now the last line will not compile, if a property in `pages` does not conform to the `PageConfig` type (see [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgcwgYQPYDsBmBLBUC8UA3gFBTlQCuATgDYBcUAzsNduggNxkXDbC0IjFmw7cKUAMaoAtmAwR0wRnHQhuAX24lp6FlDCIITAsR7kAFrKFmJEmgygByAPROANObt8BNp1ZkIDy8NTwlqSkEmRlI7CgdGVxY4PkkXCKjguPIfQUSM4yzs6TkFJUYACgBKAgA+KHRI2jCKUK84ACNUSmVbbITnF2TUl07u4CK43L8xnsm7Evl0RV7quoamlvI2jSg4E10WbVBIKAB9AGVISWwcSXgkJjQsXFMTiFRMAyMmY-BoM4AQSYD2MAB4ACr1QixCgAbQAklB2FAANYQECfKAQgC6jAhiJxUAgAA9gIoACYmUHPHB4AD8sCMtNeiQg1GoqGoTk0JBI7yZjxZeEIQJBPzBl2ut2w9x+wtq2hcLigwFQeyYTHZwHcqosKUFxmFyJMADc4LRsBT+f9zmdkBYIJJUQB5dC0EA0jB0piQ4lkykmIhQOGo4SsdgIPGG40aaHEKAaG2nM5nSSO52mVMOp2u92e5ne3C+0FPIsIerK4kcrkmCmUaBq5Hoc2WilQALQMCcyDUUBAA))

You have to decide if you want these complicated types, but with a simple `pages` declaration or the more verbose version when declaring `pages` but with easier to understand types...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Const assertion that you mentioned is most definitely very useful in that case and overall great thing to know. I made an edit to better explain my goal, cause `PagesConfig` type is overall not needed elsewhere. What I was trying to achieve is that typescript would automatically ensure every entry in `pages` to follow `PageConfig` interface but without explicitly writing `as PageConfig`.`pages` config is a really big object and it would be unpractical to remember to type every entry this way.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. It was very helpful and thanks to it I achieved exactly the effect I wanted to. 

One more thing that I'm currently struggling with is the best way to avoid error while using `pages` dynamically, for example: `pages[page].allow` which results in error that `allow` property does not exists on one of the `pages` entries. I came up with 2 solutions:

1. Explicitly set `pages` type - `(pages as PagesConfig)` where needed 
2. Export `pages = {...} as const` and `pagesConfig: PagesConfig = pages;`

Any ideas how to make it in more efficient and elegant way?